# How to hide the title bar through code in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I want to hide the title bar using code for some of my activities.

I have used the following code

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
//Remove notification bar
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

the second line is working for full screen but it shows the application title. Lets say for my splash screen i want to hide my title. The 1st line of code crashes my application. Please help me if we can do it using code.

thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To hide title bar and status bar:

```
try
   {((View)act.findViewById(android.R.id.title).getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
catch (Exception e) {}
act.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
act.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
view.requestLayout();
```

To show title bar and status bar:

```
try
   {((View)act.findViewById(android.R.id.title).getParent()).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
catch (Exception e) {}
act.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
act.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
view.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Can I just ask, in the end you call requestLayout on what view? Also, the first line of your answer (the one that suppose to hide the title) crashes my app :s

Comment: yeah me too confused.

Answer (score 22):

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

You should call this before your **setContentView()** method, did you do that?

You could always do it in your manifest by adding `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` to your activity

Comment: flag as answered then, please :)

Comment: This works, but even if I call this before setContentView(),the title shows itself for a second and than the activity is displayed full screen. Has someone noticed this, and knows a solution??

Answer (score 8):

If you are using API 11 and above

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide(); // slides out
actionBar.show(); // slides in
```

Comment: i want to remove title if<api 11 and want to show title bar if api>11

Comment: I had to change the code to ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar() to use the androidx library.

Answer (score 2):

for remove **Application Titlebar** then add this line

`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

before **setContentView(R.layout.main);**

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure you are calling **setContentView** after these 2 lines

Answer (score 0):

Update for 2022. Works in Android 9+ (at least) and you can call it after setContentView()

// Hide action bar
Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();

// Show action bar
Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).show();