# How to hide Android title bar after window creation?

Tags: android

[How to hide the title bar through code in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872376/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-through-code-in-android) describes a simple way to hide the window title bar, but it needs to be done before calling setContentView. What if I want to do it later? In my case, I'd like to do it after a web view has finished loading content and I no longer need to show progress in the title bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple options that involve ditching the title bar altogether:

- Inflate a layout using `LayoutInflater`. This layout will essentially be the `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` that holds all of the components for your **title bar**.
- or if that sounds like too much of a hastle you can create a **title bar** in your xml of the activity with the visibility set to **gone** and use `titleBarLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` when web view is done loading

Pseudo code:

```
RelativeLayout activityLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
LayoutInflater inflater       = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

public void onWebViewFinishLoading() {
      LinearLayout myTitleBar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_title_bar, activityLayout, false);

      //Set the view to the top of the screen
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
      myTitleBar.setLayoutParams(params);

      //set up buttons, listeners, etc.
}
```

Personally, I'd go with the `LayoutInflater` option. But it's up to you. I believe you can also add animations to your title bar being displayed with either option, which could be a nice addition.

---

Or call this before `setContentView`:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
```

This will return false if a custom title bar is not supported, so you may want to check for that. This is called after `setContentView`:

```
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title_bar);
```

Assign the parent layout of the xml file (the `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` that holds all of the views) an id with `android:id="@+id/custom_title_layout"`.

Now,

```
LinearLayout titleBarLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.custom_title_layout);
```

And toggle the title bar to be there or not using :

```
titleBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);  //View.VISIBLE to show
```

Comment: I want to use the standard title bar but then remove it later.

Comment: See bottom. I still recommend the other way though. A view just hiding and showing out of nowhere with no animation looks pretty lame.

Comment: Accepting since it sounds promising, though I haven't verified. I was hoping for something simpler but have now switched to a different UI that doesn't require hiding title bar.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using API 11 and above

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide(); // slides out
actionBar.show(); // slides in
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide title bar in an activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    ...
}
```

Please refer to http://mgmblog.com/2008/12/08/hide-the-title-bar-in-an-android-view-by-using-the-window-class/

Comment: That is not after window creation as question specified.

Comment: Why people never read question carefully before submit their answer?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

in `onCreate`

```
this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
```

and then in `WebViewClient`

```
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            View title = getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            View titleBar = (View) title.getParent();
            titleBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            titleBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            activity.setTitle("");
            View title = getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            View titleBar = (View) title.getParent();
            titleBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

in xml use

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName" 
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Comment: That is not after window creation as question specified