# Show white screen until layout is completely constructed

Tags: android, layout

My problem is that I have complicated layout, and when my application starts, I see how every view is adding to layout. I see my custom window title bar construction too. I see empty custom window title, with gradient background on start, and then 1 - 2 sec later I see completed window title with my views.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title);
```

Is there simple way to show white screen, until my activity and custom title bar will be completely constructed?
The main trouble is that I cant start application with no title, and then add custom window title.
Only solution I know is splash screen, but it is too complicated for just this small task.

Comment: you can use progress dialog to hold the screen until you finish loading

Comment: maybe your layout is too complex?

Comment: Actually layout is not so complex. The only problem now, is that I see  empty window title, with my height and background. I dont actually see layout construction process, just window title construction.

Comment: In other words, activity must be started without title bar, and then I must add it, but if I initially set no title, I can't then call getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title); (it fails - "You cannot combine custom title with other title features")

Answer (score 0):

Use an asynctask like this:

```
private class LoadingMyView extends AsyncTask<void, void, int> {

     protected void onPreExecute ()
     {
             requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
             setContentView(R.layout.main);
             getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title);
             //show whiteView
     }
     protected int doInBackground() {

         return 0;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(int result) {
        //Hide white View
     }
}
```

Note: I didnt test the code but i think more or less is ok

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29)

Comment: View can't override my custom title bar

Comment: try to hide it onPreExecute, and show in postExecute, I didnt try this and dont know if it works.

Comment: did u get it? some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872376/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-through-code-in-android

Comment: No, onPre and onPost executes on ui thread, so there is no difference where to setContentView and custom title